# show a larger version of thumbnail image with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to get my (JQuery) code to show a larger version of my thumbnail image. 
At this moment I have this code, which only shows the thumbnail in "full size":

```
$(".gallerythumbnail").click(function() {
    $(".showimagelightdown, .showimagecontainer, .closeimage").fadeIn(300);
    var img = $('<img />', { src : this.src });
    $('.showimagecontainer').html(img).show();
});
```

I have tried different approaches, including the following:

```
$(".gallerythumbnail").click(function() {
    $(".showimagelightdown, .showimagecontainer, .closeimage").fadeIn(300);
    var img = $('<img />', { src : 'f'+this.src });
    $('.showimagecontainer').html(img).show();
});
```

Above I tried to add an "f" to the image path, which would be the full version of the thumbnail, but without luck.
So, is it possible to add something to the path of the clicked image? Or is there a smarter way for doing this?

As for the html, I have a loop (PHP) running throught all images in a folder an printing them out as follows:

```
print "<td><a href='#'><img src='".$picsarray[$picsfrom]."' class='gallerythumbnail'></a></td>";
```

Comment: Do you have different images for the larger version?

Comment: Can you also show some of your HTML.

Comment: Hanlet: yes I have a different image for the larger version.
putvande: I have added the relevant part of my html

Comment: Retsam: what do you mean by Zoom in/Enhance?

Comment: And what is `$picsarray[$picsfrom]`? And what would it be if you add `f` in front of it?

Comment: $picsarray[$picsfrom] is the path of the thumbnail, generated by a loop in my php code. When 'f" is added in front of it, it should be the large/full version of that image

Comment: @user68621 not exactly. If you have 'myPic.jpg' and then you add a f, it'd be 'myPic.jpgf', which is probably why you are not getting the desired output. You need to add the f before the period. So you can use a replace, and replace .jpg with f.jpg.

Comment: Hanlet: I am adding 'f' before the image path. So 'myPic.jpg' would be 'fmyPic.jpg'.

Comment: @user68621 is there a place where we could see this live?

Comment: Sorry I dont have a webserver to upload it to at this moment. But what I want to know is, if it's possible to change the src in the img tag with JQuery after clicking it.

Comment: @user68621 then please copy the rendered html, and paste it in jsbin or jsfiddle, that is the only thing I can think about right now. Copy the entire generated table.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YjNwb/

Comment: @user68621 Sorry; that was a joke.

Comment: @user68621 look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the 'f' at the beginning of your fullpath, instead of the beginning of the filename.

So if you have the following path:

```
http://mydomain.com/galleries/gallery2/4886193_460s.jpg
```

you are doing this:

```
fhttp://mydomain.com/galleries/gallery2/4886193_460s.jpg
```

Try this:

```
$(".gallerythumbnail").click(function() {
        $(".showimagelightdown, .showimagecontainer, .closeimage").fadeIn(300);
        var path = this.src.replace(/[^\/]*$/,'');
        var filename = this.src.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '')

        var img = $('<img />', { src : path + 'f' + filename});     
        $('.showimagecontainer').html(img).show();
    });
```

This will create the src like this:

```
http://mydomain.com/galleries/gallery2/f4886193_460s.jpg
```